# See SQLite db contents

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, eclipse-plugin, adt

I'm developing an android app using sqllite db and I wanted to know if there way a way to explore this db's current content.

Comment: try using sqlite manager import your database to local s/m and view using sqlite manager (firefox plugins are available)

Comment: On linux you can use [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Download SqlLite Database Browser](http://www.razorsql.com/docs/sqlite_database_browser.html).

you need to pull a copy of the database from the device or emulator as explained below and work on that copy that can be restored later on.

The database for a specific app lives in /data/data/[packagename]/databases

The packagename is the package you define in your manifest, for instance /data/data/org.example.com/databases/counts.db.

You can view it with adb shell, to see database type sqlite3 /data/data/org.example.com/databases/counts.db

**Or you can pull it from the device to look** at it with a third party utility, with a command like adb pull /data/data/org.example.com/databases/counts.db ..

Comment: its a great app yet at least on OS X there is no sqlite FTS support. Is there a way to enable it for SqlLite Database Browser or is there another tool around?